# Cannot create hypertable in timescaleDb

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I installed timescaleDb using Docker following this tutorial for the setup: https://docs.timescale.com/self-hosted/latest/install/installation-docker/ . I used this image : `timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest`

Then I connected to the instance with pgAdmin and followed this official tutorial: https://docs.timescale.com/getting-started/latest/tables-hypertables/.

```
CREATE DATABASE "test-timescale";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Measurements" (
    "Id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "DeviceId" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "SensorId" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "Timestamp" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    "Temperature" DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
```

However when I try to run the command for creating hypertables I get an error that the `by_range` function does not exist

```
SELECT create_hypertable('Measurements', by_range('Timestamp'));
```

The error:

```
LINE 1: SELECT create_hypertable('Measurements', by_range('Timestamp...
                                                 ^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I checked that I have the timescaleDb extension installed and created. Also tried changing the quotes to doubles, but without success.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably trying to use [TimescaleDB 2.13+ syntax](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/create_hypertable/) (the `by_range()` thing) on an earlier version. You can revert to the [old one](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/create_hypertable_old/). Note the case-sensitivity. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/2jkYsPcf)

```sql
ALTER TABLE "Measurements" DROP CONSTRAINT "Measurements_pkey";
SELECT create_hypertable('"Measurements"', 'Timestamp');
```

When running this, `"Id"` can't be a primary key, because it would mean it's unique on its own; Timescale requires that if there's a unique constraint, the partition key [needs to be a part of it](https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/schema-management/indexing/#best-practices-for-indexing):

> To define an index as a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` index, the index must include the time column and the partitioning column, if you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

So I have made a couple of mistakes. First of all I had my table named with a capital letter, which just creates additional headaches in Postgresql, where I would need to wrap the variable in double quotes inside single quotes (eg. '"Measurement"'). Secondly I had a primary key constraint added to the `Id` which made it impossible for the function to create the necessary tables.

So I have made a workaround using:

```
SELECT create_hypertable('measurements', 'Timestamp', if_not_exists => TRUE, chunk_time_interval => INTERVAL '1 day');
```

This command now worked and I have succesfully created the hypertable.

However I am still interested in why the `by_range` function does not work out of the box like it is described in the documentation. If anyone can clear that up I would be delighted.

Comment: Looks like I should've posted earlier: [the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2jkYsPcf) still shows `14:31:17` UTC cached as a `now()` result but between me finishing the demo and posting [the answer with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77800853/5298879) at `14:37:31`, by `14:35:02` you managed to clarify most of this on your own. Still, you might find the explanation for the missing `by_range` part of the issue, useful, so I'll leave it up